# Banshee installation, unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies, banshee

I am running ubuntu 15.04 on a Lenovo yoga 3 pro
I'm having trouble installing the banshee media player. When I attempt to install via the Software Center, I get the following notification:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
banshee: Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.44.1) but 2.44.0-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
     Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.27-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsoup-gnome2.4-1 (>= 2.27.4) but 2.49.92-1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.26.1) but 2.49.92-1 is to be installed
     Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.6.0) but 2:1.6.2-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
     Depends: mono-runtime (>= 3.0~) but 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libc0.1 (>= 2.21) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libgconf2.0-cil (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.2-3 is to be installed
     Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.31.3) but 2.31.3-1 is to be installed
     Depends: libglib2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but 2.12.10-5.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgtk2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but 2.12.10-5.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-cairo4.0-cil (>= 3.2.1) but 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 3.2.8) but 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-posix4.0-cil (>= 3.2.3) but 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-system-core4.0-cil (>= 3.2.8) but 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 3.2.1) but 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 3.2.8) but 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: gnome-icon-theme (>= 2.16) but 3.12.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

So I tried to install via the terminal, with this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install banshee
```

which gave me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 banshee : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.44.1) but 2.44.0-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
       Recommends: banshee-extension-soundmenu (= 2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm still pretty new with Ubuntu, so I'd appreciate simpleton-style explanations...thank you!

I was referred to this question: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) which I don't think was effective-
I may not be following the directions appropriately it seems a little unrelated to me.  here is my terminal history of the troubleshooting I tried from the question:

```
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for will: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo apt-get -f install banshee
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 banshee : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.44.1) but 2.44.0-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
           Recommends: banshee-extension-soundmenu (= 2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a banshee
dpkg: error: --configure --pending does not take any non-option arguments

>Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo apt-get -f install banshee
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 banshee : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.44.1) but 2.44.0-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
           Recommends: banshee-extension-soundmenu (= 2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo apt-get clean
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ sudo apt-get -f install banshee
Reading package lists... 7%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 banshee : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.44.1) but 2.44.0-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
           Recommends: banshee-extension-soundmenu (= 2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Requested info:

```
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ apt-cache policy libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.44.0-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 2.44.0-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 2.44.0-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ apt-cache policy banshee
banshee:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu5
  Version table:
     2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
will@will-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: This question really needs extra attention because  [banshee (2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu5)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid-updates/banshee) depends on ***libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.44.1)***, but version present in repositoy is [2.44.0-1ubuntu3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libglib2.0-0).

Comment: what's the output for `apt-cache policy libglib2.0-0`?

Comment: and also what is the output `apt-cache policy banshee`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with banshee (dependency on libglib2.0 2.44.1). It looks like banshee came out of the proposed repository sooner than the  libglib it is dependent on.

I was able to work around this as follows:

1. Enable vivid-proposed
2. Upgrade libglib

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0/vivid-proposed libglib2.0-bin/vivid-proposed
   ```
3. Disable proposed
4. Install/upgrade banshee

Probably not the cleanest way (presumably waiting for 2.44.1) but it worked for me.

Comment: Wow!  thank you very much, I'm not sure why this is the current setup.  I haven't tried installing banshee since 23 June, so it's possible that updates between now and then enabled me to install.  However, after doing the steps you described, I did get an install.  I was thinking it wouldn't work, because my terminal said that the updates were not found, however you are probably correct with the update mismatch.  thanks again!